# Inner join only returns 7 records

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join

I've got a table with 500.000 records filled with Twitter updates. Then I've got a table with user info.

I basically need all the Twitter records of the people in my user table.

I can do it with this SELECT IN query:

```
SELECT *
FROM STATUS WHERE twitterUserID
IN (    
    SELECT twitteruserid
    FROM accountLink
)
```

But that's obviously very slow.

I then tried to do it with a join, but it only shows 7 records. No idea why.

```
SELECT status . * , accountLink.userId, accountLink.twitterUserId
FROM status
JOIN accountLink
ON status.twitterUserId = accountLink.twitterUserId
```

Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour and how to solve it?

Comment: select *
from status as s
inner join accountLink as a on s.twiteruserid = a.twitteruserid

try that.

Comment: If anything, I would expect that the second query would give you more rows than the first. Can you create a small set of data that demonstrates the problem? Data for each table, expected outcome, and what you're getting would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
SELECT status.* , accountLink.userId, accountLink.twitterUserId
FROM status
LEFT JOIN accountLink
ON status.twitterUserId = accountLink.twitterUserId
```

I suspect that there aren't matches for all the records between status and account link.  Doing a left join will select every `status` regardless of whether or not `accountLink` has a match.

Comment: I thought that at first, but the way I read the original "IN" statement, it sounds as if he only is trying to get statuses for accounts that have an accountLink match... so I'm not sure why the 2 statements don't give the same return...

Comment: Yeah that's a good point.  I'd probably have to see your data to figure out why you are seeing this.  Is `twitterUserId` an int for both tables?

Comment: This is probably a type conversion issue - IN() will cast between types whereas = won't. Need more schema information.

Comment: twitterUserId is an unsigned bigint(19) in both tables. Using InnoDB

Comment: Hmmm sounds like shenanigans.  Would it be possible for you to post two rows from each table.  One that is being included and one that is not?

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN syntax should work, unless the column data types are different.

Per the [MySQL Documentation for IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This means IN is very quick if the IN value list consists entirely of constants. Otherwise, type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 11.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the arguments.

Ensuring that your column types match should ensure that the JOIN syntax works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*, a.twitterUserId, a.userId
FROM status AS s INNER JOIN accountLink AS a
WHERE s.twitterUserId=a.twitterUserId
```

You DO want to use inner join because you only want to return results IF the "status" table has a record AND a corresponding user record is found in the "accountLink" table. If a "status" table record does NOT have a corresponding user entry, you shouldn't display it (at least according to your post). LEFT OUTER JOIN would display status table records even if there was not a matching entry in the accountLink table.

Here's a great resource for learning about SQL joins:
[SQL Joins (w3schools.com)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)